# How to query all data with current date when column is datetime in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, date, datetime, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I have created table with field createdDate as DATETIME. Now I am trying to get all the data with same date regardless of the time

For example
createdDate values are

```
2022-02-02 10:00:00
2022-03-02 12:00:00
2022-04-10 12:00:00
2022-04-12 12:00:00
2022-04-12 13:00:00
```

Lets say today is April 12 and I want all data that has been created today, this is my query statement

```
SELECT * from sample WHERE createdDate = date('now')
```

I need to get all those with 2022-04-12 dates but I'm getting none. Is this possible or I have no choice but to use DATE as field type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should strip off the time part of your timestamps with the function `date()`:

```
WHERE date(createdDate) = date('now')
```

or:

```
WHERE date(createdDate) = CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: thanks this works! I never thought we can put column name inside date function.